# How to resolve cyclical links in typedefs?

Tags: c++, typedef, cyclic-reference

I need to resolve this thing somehow:

```
  class MyType; // this thing doesn't help here
  typedef std::stack<boost::variant<int, std::function<shared_ptr<MyType>()>>> MyType;
```

I get an error like this one

```
 error C2371: 'MyType': redefinition; different basic types
```

Any help will be appreciate.

**Edit:**

This can be done easily with using structure as proxy:

```
struct MyStruct;
typedef std::stack<boost::variant<int, std::function<shared_ptr<MyStruct>()>>> MyType;
struct MyStruct {
    MyType data;
};
```

But must be more handy way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible with either `typedef` or `using`.  However, in the abstract, this question doesn't necessarily concern boost.  A generic template could be constructed to cause this problem.  Posing the question in a more general way may help attract more attention to the problem.

Comment: Yes, you right, Robert. I have made it more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, because what you are asking for causes an infinite recursion:

```
typedef std::stack<boost::variant<int, std::function<shared_ptr<MyType>()>>> MyType;
MyType a;
```

would expand to:

```
std::stack<boost::variant<int, std::function<shared_ptr<
    std::stack<boost::variant<int, std::function<shared_ptr<
        std::stack<boost::variant<int, std::function<shared_ptr<
            *Infinitely many more here*
        ()>>>>
    ()>>>>
()>>> a;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Potentially infinite deep structure.

Comment: Yes, an potentially infinitely deep *structure*, but not a infinitely deep *type*. Without a better explanation I can only guess, but I would expect that what you really want is a stack of variants which are either `int` or `function`-pointers.

Comment: Perhaps I should do it with struct proxy (as I add to the head of this post), but still it looks odd for me. Or... I can return from function not `MyType`, but `void*` and then cast in to `MyType`. Perversion from any side.

Comment: I guess, I'll stop on struct proxy for now